# How would I organize this to print out all questions in my table with possible answers?

Tags: html, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to display 4 questions that I have in my database and display the possible answers for each question. Each question should have a different input type for its answers though. So if question one has radio buttons, I want question 2 to have checkboxes, and 3 to have text and so on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<h1>Please complete the short survey below:</h1>


    <%= @submission.campaign.name %> 

    <form>
    <ul>
        <ol>

    <% for question in @submission.campaign.questions %>

            <li><%= question.question_verbiage %></li>
                <ul>



            <ol type = 'A'>
                    <% for possible_answer in question.possible_answers %>
                            <input type = 'radio' name = "possible_answer" value= "<%= possible_answer.id%>">
                            <li><%= possible_answer.answer_verbiage %></li>
                    <% end %>
                </ol>
            </ul>
```

This is to help explain what I want to happen.This would be perfect if the question.verbiage below was question 2 but instead its question 1 again.

```
<li><%= question.question_verbiage %></li>

            <ul>

                <ol type = 'A'>
                    <% for possible_answer in question.possible_answers %>
                            <input type = 'scale' name = "possible_answer" value= "<%= possible_answer.id%>">
                            <li><%= possible_answer.answer_verbiage %></li>
                    <% end %>
                </ol>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

kind of broad but, try adding something like render_type to your answer or question model and create a helper function that uses that value to determine which type to use.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag

i didn't test this

```
def answer_input_helper(answer)
  content_tag(:input, '', :type=>answer.type)
end


----


<% question.possible_answers.each do |a| %>
<%= input_helper(a) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: wow that sounds helpful but where would I define that at? And would that be all I need to type?

Comment: after you change your model with a migration, you can put the helper function into the helper module for your resource.  i think the directory is app/helpers.  if it isn't there just create it.  the rest goes in your view.